# Calling native component function from React native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to create a custom component which will draw a graphic using OpenGL. What i'm hoping to do is call a function within these components from javascript that will start the drawing process so that all the animations begin in sync. I've read through the documentation and i see that you can call a function thats within a native *module* but i can't find a way to do it within a native *component*. How would this be best accomplished?

Adam

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, you're looking to essentially make your own view that is native-powered, and construct the bridge properties that will be passed through to your React Native app.

You'll need to create a view manager.  There's friendly documentation on how to do this [here on Facebook docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html).

Using this method you can wrap a native component in JavaScript and expose certain properties.  I have an example of this in C# for React Native Windows that is super simple.  You might be afraid of reading C#, but it's essentially the same process as you'd have to do in Android.  C# and Java are so logically aligned.  [Here's the aforementioned example](https://github.com/GantMan/WinGif).

This will give you a fully native component that was initialized and is controlled via JavaScript.